# Cancel macro 1 if macro 2 is running

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macros altogether, one macro assigned to my `Private Worksheet_Change event` and the other assigned to my `Private Worksheet_SelectionChange` event like so:

Macro 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


'If Hours Column Selected
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row)) Is Nothing And Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value <> "" Then


NewValue = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Your Delegated Reference:")
If NewValue <> vbNullString Then

Dim rw2 As Long, cell2 As Range
rw2 = ActiveCell.Row
    With Worksheets("Data").Columns("I:I")
        Set cell2 = .find(What:=NewValue, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cell2 Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        cell2.Offset(0, 4).Value = Sheet1.Range("Y" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        cell2.Offset(0, 5).Value = Sheet1.Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        cell2.Offset(0, 6).Value = Sheet1.Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

        MsgBox "Found"


        Sheet1.Range("Y" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Sheet1.Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Sheet1.Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 3).Value

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True


        Else

        MsgBox "Not Found"
        Sheet1.Range("A5").Select
        End If

        End With



Else

If NewValue = vbNullString Then
MsgBox "Not Found"
Sheet1.Range("A5").Select

End If
End If


End If

End Sub
```

Macro 2

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Y" & ActiveCell.Row)) Is Nothing Then

        myValue3 = MsgBox("This is a message")

End If


    End Sub
```

The problem I have is when I click on my active cell row in column Z I am running macro 1 and asking it to update the value of my active cell row in column Y. However when the information in column Y is updated, it is causing macro 2 to run where I get a msgbox displaying and I don't want this to happen.

Whilst I still require macro 2 and do want the msgbox to display, I only want it to display when I click on the cell in column Y. So in other words, I want to be able to cancel out macro 2 if macro 1 is running.

I have tried using `application.displayevents = false` in macro 1 but this doesn't work.

Please can someone show me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

.. at the start of your macro1 to disable events and

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

To turn it back on again at the end of macro1.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. However, I tried this as well but my macro 1 then doesn't update the cells because enable events are false :/

Comment: It should work if you turn it off/on within macro 1. This cannot result in macro1 itself not getting triggered

Comment: Are you sure you used `EnableEvents`, since you mentioned `DisplayEvents`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

[1] Add a new Module to your VBA Project, with the following:

```
Public EventRunning as Boolean
```

[2] Modify your Worksheet_SelectionChange macro as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
    EventRunning=True
    ...
    EventRunning=False
End Sub
```

[3] Modify your Worksheet_Change as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  
    If EventRunning Then Exit Sub
    ...
```

Best wishes Ben